# How to get inkStroke points Coordinates relative to device screen?

Tags: c#, uwp, inkcanvas

Class `InkStroke` contains a methond `GetInkPoints()` and the points `Position` attribute is ralative to inking area, I want to convert the points coordinates relative to screen device dpi, are there any methond in UWP can do this?

Comment: Relative to screen coordinates or the app coordinates?

Comment: Screen coordinates